# Specify same folder the Dockerfile is as context in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this folder structure:

```
-Project
|__Service1
   |_ DockerFile
   |_ ...
|__Docker
   |_ Service1
      |_docker-compose.yaml
```

I want to be able to run docker-compose from Docker/Sevice1 folder to build (if it doesn't exist) the Service1 image and run the image.

This is the docker-compose file I use (part of it):

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  admin:
    build:
      context: ../../Service1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And this is the DockerFIle inside Project/Service1:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

...

COPY . /var/www/html/
```

As you see I'm trying to copy files in Project/Service1 into the container but it is copying the files at Project/Docker.

This build command builds the image correctly though:

```
 docker build -t feendi/Service1 -f ../../Service1/Dockerfile ../../Service1
```

when it is ran from Project/Docker/Service1

How could I run the docker file in Project/Docker/Service1 and build the image with the docker file at Project/Service1 copying what is inside Project/Service1 into the final image?

Comment: Your configuration looks OK. Can you verify with `docker-compose config`, that absolute path to Project/Service1 is correct? Also, there can't be any symlink mess?!

Comment: How are you verifying that the wrong content is copied into the image?  Is there something else (maybe a `volumes:` block) that's replacing the image content?  (Since your Dockerfile is in the root of the context directory, you should not need a Compose `dockerfile:` or `docker build -f` option; it's in its default location.

Comment: That was it, After thousand of tests, I forgot to remove one of the mapped volumes. I was so focused... Thanks for that!